# PHP URL 'Redirecting'

Tags: php, url

Say if you visit my site: http://nesmods.com/page/2/ there isn't actually a /page/2/ on my site, Wordpress somehow catches the URL and generates a page based on the URL. What is the name of this technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This redirecting is managed by the [**mod_rewrite Module**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) of Apache. Normally this is done in the `.htaccess` file. Depending on the configuration of your FTP program you can see them as hidden files in the Wordpress root directory.

Some further explanations and examples: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite - and Google of course.

Answer (score 1):

[Clean URLs](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Clean_URLs) apparently.  Often done through `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, referred to as URL routing or [URL rewriting](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting). Wordpress uses URL routing to map URL structures to it's internal functions that generate content.

It can also be done with the web server itself, such as URL Rewriting with Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apache hava a module of rewrite url。
It is a good search engine optimization。
This is a detail info about rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html